# copy network configuration from one linux machine to another

Tags: centos, networking, vpn, amazon-linux

I have a remote machine that runs Amazon Linux, with super user permissions to it. Its signed on to a certain network with maybe a certain network configuration, that allows it to directly access certain URLs that I can only otherwise access through a VPN on other machines.

The problem is, its very prone to outages and provides with a horrendous experience, due to geographical locations. I was thinking, maybe, I could copy its network configuration somehow and use it on my personal CentOS machine, so that I can access those same URLs but this time without the need for the VPN. The VPN in question is unfortunately closed source and does not have a proper Linux port that I can use without Wine.

Are there any methods that I can use to do this? A little bit of Linux noob here.

Comment: A network configuration is specific to the physical or logical network that the system is connected to. You can't copy a config from a system on one network to a system on a different network and have it work.

Answer (score 2):

No.

> that allows it to directly access certain URLs that I can only otherwise access through a VPN on other machines

The most likely reason is that this machine's IP address (or at least the IP address is uses to connect - may be using NAT/Proxy) is configured where these URLs are hosted. Public IP addresses are not portable. If you try using this ip address on a machine outside of AWS you won't be able to connect to anything.

There are a whole lot of very esoteric things which could give rise to a situation where only this host can connect to those URLs (there's not much point in listing them here) but they all reside outside the network config.